# Wrapping a function in count

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

I am working through the *Programming Paradigms via Mathematica (A First Course)* and am attempting to answer the following:

> Use recursion to count how many times the argument can have its square
>   root taken before the result is less than 2:  "manySqrt[x_Real]"
>   should report how many times the "Sqrt[]" function has to be applied
>   to "x" before the result is less than 2.  For instance, Sqrt[81.0] is
>   9.0, Sqrt[9.0] is 3.0 and Sqrt[3.0] is less than 2 so, "manySqrt[81.0]" is 3.  Of course, don't use a logarithm.

Additionally:

> First, use of a repetition function ("Map[]", "MapThread[]", "Nest[]",
>   "NestList[]", "Fold[]", "FoldList[]", "Table[]", "Apply[]", and so on,
>   being our "adverbs") will generally disqualify a method as purely
>   recursive, for the repetition is accomplished externally from the
>   nested function calls.  Also, repetition accomplished with a loop
>   structure, such as a "While[]", a "Do[]", or some other repetition
>   command, is explicitly forbidden.

My strategy is to make a list of 'Real' values and then count the 'Real' values in the list. I can get the following to work:

```
Clear[manySqrt]
manySqrt[x_Real] := If[x >= 2, Flatten[Append[{x}, manySqrt[Sqrt[x]]]]]

 manySqrt[81.]

(* {81., 9., 3., Null} *)

 Count[%, _Real]

(* 3 *)
```

However I get an erroneous answer when I try to wrap `Count` as follows:

```
Clear[manySqrt]
manySqrt[x_Real] := 
 If[x >= 2, Count[Flatten[Append[{x}, manySqrt[Sqrt[x]]]], _Real]]

 manySqrt[81.]

 (* 1 *)
```

I would appreciate a point in the right direction.

Comment: Your new function is outputting the Count[ ] instead of the new square root (presumably that's what the "1" is in the answer).

Comment: @bills, Let me use this as a ‘learnable’ moment. My understanding was that `Flatten[Append[{x}, manySqrt[Sqrt[x]]]]` produced a list of real numbers;  so that if I wrapped `Count … _Real` around it, `Count` would count the number of real numbers in that list. But from what I gather you are telling me is that `Count` actually only counted the number of times `Count` was invoked. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: I think rm -rf described below in great detail what is happening in your second attempt -- the output of the function is the count, not the square roots... as it was in your first attempt. Using rm -rf's definition, try `Trace[manySqrt[81.]]` and you can follow exactly how the function is working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're learning, it'll be instructive to know *why* your solution didn't work. For that, let's try replacing `Count` with `count` (note the lower case `c`), which doesn't have any definitions attached with it (clear it first if you have) and evaluate the function:

```
ClearAll[manySqrt2, count]
manySqrt2[x_Real] := If[x >= 2, count[Flatten[Append[{x}, manySqrt2[Sqrt[x]]]], _Real]]

manySqrt2[1000.] (* test *)
(* count[{1000., count[{31.6228, count[{5.62341, 
       count[{2.37137, Null}, _Real]}, _Real]}, _Real]}, _Real] *)
```

So you can see that the eventual solution is a final "count" of the individual counts, not the square root values at each recursion (which is what you tried to do). Since the output of `Count` is an `Integer`, the final evaluation will always be of the form:

```
Count[{Real, Integer, Integer, Integer, ..., Null}, Real]
```

which is always `1`.

In general, it is always good to approach recursive definitions by first defining a "stopping condition". For instance, your solution does not return anything (or returns `Null`) for input < 2, when it should return 0. I would've written the definition as

```
ClearAll[manySqrt]
manySqrt[x_Real] /; x < 2 = 0;
manySqrt[x_Real] := 1 + manySqrt[√x]
```

I find this much more readable and maintainable than the `If` based approach, because it is immediately clear what the function does and it is easily extendable to more than one criterion.

Comment: "more than one criterion" - I guess the choice of using multiple definitions or `Which[]`/`Switch[]` is a matter of taste, but you're right that in recursive solutions, one should always think about the "base case" first, and build from there.

Comment: @rm -rf, Thank you for showing me what I did wrong as well as a code that accomplished what I wanted. I’ll add that running `Trace` (as @bills suggested) was illuminating.

Answer (score 9):

I'd have done it this way:

```
manySqrt[x_Real] := If[x < 2, 0, 1 + manySqrt[Sqrt[x]]]
```

Comment: I'd rather set `x_?NumericQ` or `x_?Positive` instead of `x_Real`.

Comment: Me too, but the problem statement demanded `manySqrt[x_Real]`, so here we are. :)

Comment: @J. M., Very nice and compact code, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

As in my last answer I suggest an implementation which has *one detail* per line for readability

```
sqrtCount[x_] := sqrtCount[x, 0];
sqrtCount[x_ /; x >= 2, c_] := sqrtCount[Sqrt[x], c + 1];
sqrtCount[_, c_] := c
```

`c` is the recursion *count* and the rest should be obvious then.

Comment: will try to remember ‘one detail per line’ in the future. Thank You again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
manySqrt[x_Real /; x >= 2] := manySqrt[Sqrt[x]]    
manySqrt[x_Real] := "below"

Trace[manySqrt[81.], Sqrt[_]]
```

> {{Sqrt[81.]},{Sqrt[9.]},{Sqrt[3.]}}

```
Length@%
```

> 3

Comment: Thanks for working on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Either [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26670/wrapping-a-function-in-count/26672#26672) or [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26670/wrapping-a-function-in-count/26675#26675) answer is the way I would do it, but in the spirit in which solution in the question began, here's a way to use `Count`:

```
manySqrt[x_Real, f_: Count] := If[x >= 2, f[{x, manySqrt[Sqrt[x], # &]}, _Real, Infinity]]
```

Strictly speaking, this is not a declaration of the form `manySqrt[x_Real]`, but `manySqrt[81.0]` does return 3 and so forth.

Comment: I would say that is a valid way do this, whether the prof(s) that taught the class back in the day would have I don’t know, anyway  thank you for the answer.