# How can I generate a nested array like this one?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

Well, this is how the array looks like:

[image]

I came up with this code:

```
n = 10;
Nest[ArrayPad[#, 1, 1 - #[[1, 1]]] &, {{1}}, n] /. {1 -> "*"}
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: Fun question.  Too bad every method I can think of is already posted. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You are too late for the game :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Via `CellularAutomaton`:

```
ruleFn[{{_, _, _}, {_, 0, _}, {_, _, _}}, step_] := 1;
ruleFn[{{_, _, _}, {_, 1, _}, {_, _, _}}?(MemberQ[#, 0, 2] &), step_] := 0;
ruleFn[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, step_] := 1;

CellularAutomaton[{ruleFn, {}, {1, 1}}, {{{0}}, 1}, {{{9}}}] /. 1 -> "*" // Grid
```

---

*Edit:*
For those who really like obfuscated CAs:

```
Grid[CellularAutomaton[
 {6704108548762591141713703895184498446288891439307603869437298727894782281512658462491554691453382697921609151728673186802143641955019044568101339107753983,
  2, {1, 1}}, {{{0}}, 1}, {{{9}}}] /. 1 -> "*"]
```

...or just like really large numbers.

Comment: Someday, I'll try to find time to learn more about cellular automata... (+1)

Comment: It's my favorite! And it will takes me some tough time to figure out how it works :) I accept this just due to my personal interest on `CA`, all the other answers are nice too.

Comment: @mm.Jang this method is very slow, some ~340 times slower than my `mat2`.  I know you didn't specify performance as your primary goal but this seems like a lot of code for a very slow function.  (Sorry Michael; I'm usually a fan of your answers but this just seems impractical.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No problem.  The answer was meant for fun.  Upvoted your comment because it's important for future visitors, who may have other criteria, such as efficiency, in searching for solutions.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a recursive approach:

```
f[1] = {{1}};
f[x_] := ArrayPad[f[x - 1], 1, Boole@OddQ@x];
```

To apply it and display

```
f[8] //. 1 -> "*" // MatrixForm
```

[image]

I learned this trick from rm -rf in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26670/wrapping-a-function-in-count/26675#26675) which has a great explanation of a simple recursive function. This `f[ ]` works for both even and odd matrix sizes.

Comment: Iteration version: `Nest[ArrayPad[#, 1, Boole@EvenQ@First@#] &, {{1}}, 7] //. 
  1 -> "*" // Grid`.

Answer (score 9):

> Update

Simpler way of generating a "concentric" matrix, without having to convert to an image to apply a distance transform:

```
    With[{size = 11}, 
     Array[Max[#1, #2, size + 1 - #1, size + 1 - #2] &, {size, size}] 
      /. {_?OddQ -> "0", _?EvenQ -> "*"}]
```

> End update

Here's a hare-brained implementation that uses `DistanceTransform[]`:

First create an image with a single background (value 0) pixel at the center, and remaining pixels all foreground (value 1):

`img = Image[SparseArray[{6, 6} -> 0, {11, 11}, 1]]`

Take the distance transform with the chessboard metric:

`mat = Round@ImageData@DistanceTransform[img, DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance]`

giving

[image: distance matrix]

Now simply use rule-based replacement

`mat /. {_?EvenQ -> "*", _?OddQ -> "0"} // MatrixForm`

to get the desired result.

[image: result]

Answer (score 8):

I like Bill's recursive approach. Here's another version using `ArrayPad` and `Fold`:

```
nested[n_Integer] := Fold[ArrayPad[#, 1, (-1)^#2] &, {{1}}, Range[n]] /. {-1 -> 0, 1 -> "*"}
nested[10] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear[nestmatrix]
nestmatrix[width_] := SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /;
      EvenQ[Ceiling[Norm[{i, j} - (width + 1)/2, ∞]]] :>
     "*"}, width {1, 1}, 0] // Normal

{#, Grid[
     nestmatrix[#] /.
      "*" -> Item["*", Background -> Lighter[Red, .7]],
     ItemSize -> All,
     Frame -> All,
     FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.8]]} & /@ Range[6] //
 Grid[#\[Transpose], Frame -> All] &
```

[image: examples]

You can of course replace `EvenQ` with `OddQ` to "reverse" the order.

Answer (score 7):

The `CellularAutomaton` is very cool!

Another solution based on how * and 0 positions differ is given below:

```
f[n_] := Table[If[Mod[Max[Abs[i], Abs[j]], 2] == 0, "*", "0"],
               {i, -n, n}, {j, -n, n}];

f[10]
```

Comment: Nicely done. Here's a `SparseArray[]` version: `f[n_Integer] := SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; EvenQ[Max[Abs[i - n - 1], Abs[j - n - 1]]] :> "*", {2 n + 1, 2 n + 1}]`

Answer (score 5):

A bit complicated, but:

```
With[{n = 31}, 
     SparseArray[{i_, j_} /;
                 (EvenQ[i] && (i <= j <= n - i + 1 || n - i + 1 <= j <= i)) ||
                 (EvenQ[j] && (j <= i <= n - j + 1 || n - j + 1 <= i <= j)) :> "*",
     {n, n}]]
```

`n` must be odd, of course.

---

As noted in the comments by chyanog, one might want to use `Min[]`/`Max[]` for the second set of tests for each index. Here's an alternative:

```
With[{n = 31}, 
     SparseArray[{i_, j_} /;
                 (EvenQ[i] && IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{i, n - i + 1}], j]) ||
                 (EvenQ[j] && IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{j, n - j + 1}], i]) :> "*",
                 {n, n}]]
```

Comment: (At the very least, the sparse array takes up less memory than the corresponding full array.)

Comment: I think the memory advantage will be marginal at best, it seems defining `SparseArray` with `Condition` causes it to test all possible positions and store `{position}` and `value` for all that match, in this case storing ~half the positions and a long list with only "*"s in it

Comment: Well, according to `ByteCount[mm]/ByteCount[Normal[mm]]` (where `mm` is the sparse array), it only needs more or less 2/3 of the storage for the full array; I get similar savings for larger dimensions.

Comment: This code can be simplifyed with `Min`.

Comment: @chyanog, yes, I could have used `Min[]` and `Max[]` to compress to a single interval...

Comment: There's a third argument to `SparseArray` -- you can get the memory usage down to 1/2 of `Normal`.  That `"*"` takes up a lot of room.

Comment: @Michael, yeah, but since `0` is the default value of the third argument anyway, I didn't bother.

Answer (score 5):

It's surprising that the following `For` loop approach is so fast (in fact it seems to be the fastest one until now! ):

```
(* n is the order of the matrix *)
n = 301;
mat = ConstantArray["*", {n, n}];
mid = (1 + n)/2;
mat[[mid, mid]] = 0;
For[i = 2, mid - i >= 1, i += 2, 
  mat[[mid - i, mid - i ;; mid + i]] = 0;
  mat[[mid + i, mid - i ;; mid + i]] = 0;
  mat[[mid - i + 1 ;; mid + i - 1, mid - i]] = 0;
  mat[[mid - i + 1 ;; mid + i - 1, mid + i]] = 0]
```

Here's the snapshot for the test result:

[image]

---

You may think that this code may be improved by changing the `For` loop into `Do` or `Nest`, but again, it's surprising that `Do` and `Nest` help little here, and I had a hard time in getting the boundary of the iterator. (I'm really bad at that! And thanks for the help of @chyanog ! )

```
n = 301;
mat = ConstantArray["*", {n, n}];
mid = (1 + n)/2;
mat[[mid, mid]] = 0;
Do[mat[[mid - i, mid - i ;; mid + i]] = 0;
   mat[[mid + i, mid - i ;; mid + i]] = 0;
   mat[[mid - i + 1 ;; mid + i - 1, mid - i]] = 0;
   mat[[mid - i + 1 ;; mid + i - 1, mid + i]] = 0;, {i, 2, mid - 1, 2}]

n = 301;
mat = ConstantArray["*", {n, n}];
mid = (1 + n)/2;
mat[[mid, mid]] = 0;
i = 2;
Nest[(mat[[mid - i, mid - i ;; mid + i]] = 0;
     mat[[mid + i, mid - i ;; mid + i]] = 0;
     mat[[mid - i + 1 ;; mid + i - 1, mid - i]] = 0;
     mat[[mid - i + 1 ;; mid + i - 1, mid + i]] = 0; i += 2;) &, , Floor[(mid - 1)/2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use `Do[]` instead of `For[]`?

Comment: @J. M. In fact this code is written with `Nest` at very first, but later I found that the speed will barely change even if I use `Do` or `For`……

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of flogging this equine quadruped *post mortem*, here's yet another:

```
Grid[
  MorphologicalTransform[
    SparseArray[{17, 17} -> 1, {33, 33}, 0], 
    {"Fill", "Clean", "Flip"},  17] /. 1 -> "*"]
```

using the strange options in `MorphologicalTransform`. Picture unnecessary...

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to do it differently but it's hard with so many good answers.

Hopefully this brings something unique:

```
mat[n_] := "*" Mod[1 - Array[Max@Abs@{##} &, 2n + {1,1}, -n], 2]

mat[5] // Grid
```

[image]

I thought using multiplication was clever but it appears replacement is faster when working with strings.

```
mat2[n_] := Mod[1 - Array[Max@Abs@{##} &, 2 n + {1, 1}, -n], 2] /. {1 -> "*"}

mat[500]  // Timing // First
mat2[500] // Timing // First
```

> 0.437
>
> 0.234

Answer (score 1):

```
p = {"*", 0};
n = 5;
Nest[ArrayPad[#, 1, First[p = p[[{2, 1}]]]] &, {{"*"}}, n] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & * & * & * & * & * & * & * & * & * & 0 \\
>  0 & * & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & * & 0 \\
>  0 & * & 0 & * & * & * & * & * & 0 & * & 0 \\
>  0 & * & 0 & * & 0 & 0 & 0 & * & 0 & * & 0 \\
>  0 & * & 0 & * & 0 & * & 0 & * & 0 & * & 0 \\
>  0 & * & 0 & * & 0 & 0 & 0 & * & 0 & * & 0 \\
>  0 & * & 0 & * & * & * & * & * & 0 & * & 0 \\
>  0 & * & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & * & 0 \\
>  0 & * & * & * & * & * & * & * & * & * & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Also

```
Fold[ArrayPad[#, 1, p[[#2]]] &, {{"*"}}, Mod[Range @ n, 2, 1]]
Nest[ArrayPad[#, 1, #[[1, 1]] /. {0 -> "*", "*" -> 0}] &, {{"*"}}, n]
```