# How to build a game board

Tags: graphics, matrix, algorithm

I have - rather lazily - constructed a chessboard like this:

```
board :=
 With[
  {
   a = Flatten @ Table[{1, 1, 0, 0}, {4}],
   b = Flatten @ Table[{0, 0, 1, 1}, {4}]
   },
  {a, a, b, b, a, a, b, b, a, a, b, b, a, a, b, b}
  ]

board // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
letters = 
   Transpose[{Range@15, Style[#, Bold, 16] & /@
     {"a", "", "b", "", "c", "", "d", "", "e", "", "f", "", "g", "", "h"}, Table[{0, 0}, {15}]}];

numbers = 
   Transpose[{Range@15, Style[#, Bold, 16] & /@
     {"8", "", "7", "", "6", "", "5", "", "4", "", "3", "", "2", "", "1"}, Table[{0, 0}, {15}]}];

MatrixPlot[
 board,
 ColorFunction -> "Monochrome",
 ImageSize -> 400,
 Mesh -> {{0, 16}, {0, 16}},
 PlotLabel -> Style["Chessboard\n", 16, Bold],
 FrameTicks -> {{False , numbers}, {letters , False}}]
```

[image]

**(a)** How could "board" be written in a **functional** style?

**(b)** How could such a functional solution be extended to include other boards (like a    10*10 draughtsboard or an odd 11*11 board)?

**Clarification**

In *Mathematica* it's not always easy to distinguish functional and "other" styles of programming because the language incorporates many imperative constructs such as `Do`, `Table`, `Array` etc. For the purposes of this question, reliance of such imperative constructs should be avoided to make the answer correspond to a more functional programming paradigm, and thereby to distinguish it from the closely related question  [How to make a resizable chess board?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47441/245).

A particular feature of the functional approach is that loops are replaced by recursions.

Comment: Is this what you're after?: [How to make a resizable chess board?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47441/how-to-make-a-resizable-chess-board)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Not at all - As I clearly stated I'm looking for a functional solution. The way you exploited my question is frivolous.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean.  I certainly was not being frivolous, but trying to help.

Comment: You could have written: "Thanks to @eldo an old question has come up again."

Comment: FWIW I don't understand either, and the new answers to this question are answers that would be fine as answers to the other question as well. We need a clarification.

Comment: I have to agree with Pickett -- this seems a duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Then close it. I'm happy with the answers received so far.

Comment: It's like 1788: Mr.Wizard (Louis XVI) and Pickett (Marie Antoinette) disrespect democratic vote.

Comment: @eldo I think not.  Five people agree with Pickett's comment that this is unclear; only two people have voted *for* your question.  The democratic vote is on the side of this needing additional clarity.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I count 10 upvotes to the answers of my my question. Even the court received 4 upvotes, before it closed my question. This was 1788 in Europe.

Comment: @eldo Votes for answers are not votes for the question.  If they were the [Reversal badge](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/reversal) would not exist.  Further I do not appreciate your analogy.  I am not disrespecting anyone.  You will note that the **put on hold** block states:  "Please clarify your specific problem" and that is exactly what is (or was) needed.  Do you agree with Jens' addendum?  Does that match your expectation for this question?  If so I shall reopen this.

Comment: As far as I know the people on mma.se is not attempting a revolution, this analogy is ridiculous. No one here wants Mr.Wizard or Pickett's heads on spikes just because they legitimately closed this question.

Comment: This edit seems to take a very narrow view of functional programming (FP). I thought FP was primarily about avoiding mutable states.  To say `Array` does not but `CellularAutomation` does avoid a mutable state is hardly fair.  They seem equally functional.  One *might* implement either as a loop, but that hardly matters to the programmer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At least internally, the following is a nice recursive way of thinking about the chess board:

```
MatrixPlot[CellularAutomaton[250, {0, 1}, {7, 7}]]
```

[image: board]

Not sure if this is what was meant by functional style. It's hard to make a one-liner functional.

To address extensibility: the dimensions of the board are directly dictated by the argument `{7,7}`, and the repeating pattern of the board is a consequence of the rule `250` together with an initial condition that has isolated `1`s alternating with `0`s on the first row. The beauty of cellular automata is of course that they can generate patterns of all sorts of boards, you just have to find the right rule (and starting point). But this difficulty of finding the *right initial condition* is precisely the tradeoff that you incur when trying to generate a complex result in a functional way. So I think this captures the "philosophy" of functional programming.

Comment: Wow, that's a slick use of CellularAutomaton!

Comment: @evanb Thanks - I'll skip the tick marks (they would take more code than the actual board...)

Comment: @Jens Thanks, much more than I expected. Leave the tick marks for me :)

Comment: @eldo Note how I managed to sneak philosophy into the answer! I wish I had a fitting Hegel quote here...

Comment: Es gibt ja @Jens auch noch Heine: "Ich bin ein wahnsinniger Schachspieler: Schon beim ersten Stein habe ich die Königin verloren, und doch spiel ich noch und spiele - um die Königin. Soll ich weiterspielen?"

Comment: I initially voted for this, then removed my vote.  There is really no need for something this complicated and as you said finding the needed rule is not entirely straightforward.  It's "clever" but I can't see actually using this.  (*Edit: vote restored.*)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The question asked for functional style, and this is my interpretation of what was meant. In functional programming we do loops by recursion, and `CellularAutomaton` is the embodiment of nontrivial recursion.

Comment: @Jens Great! and here's for ticks chessboard[n_] := 
 MatrixPlot[CellularAutomaton[250, {0, 1}, (n - 1) {1, 1}], 
  ColorFunction -> "Monochrome", Mesh -> {{0, n}, {0, n}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 16],
  FrameTicks -> {{False, 
     Table[{i, i, 0}, {i, 1, n}]}, {Table[{i, 
       FromCharacterCode[96 + i], 0}, {i, 1, n}], False}}, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["Chessboard\n", 16, Bold]]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I delayed my response because Jens' serious rationale made mine seem trivial. Nonetheless, people have loved cellular automata since the Game of Life. They may be obscure, but that's part of their charm; they can be a joy to figure out.  They also tend to be inefficient in *M*, if you recall [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26797). Given that "Rule 250" comprises a set of rewrite rules, one can look at *M* as an extension of CA from arrays to expressions. Yet, CA is [rarely used on this site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=CellularAutomaton).

Answer (score 7):

This seems much simpler than other answers presented:

```
Array[Plus, {8, 8}] ~Mod~ 2 // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

---

Attempting to comply with the requirements of the addendum here is a recursive solution:

```
board[n_] := board[n - 1, {{0}}]

board[n_, a_] := board[n - 1, ArrayFlatten[{{a, #\[Transpose]}, {#, 0}}] &[{1 - Last[a]}]]

board[0, a_] := a
```

Example:

```
board[8] // MatrixPlot
```

[image]

Comment: Darn, I was just getting to that (for the other question). +1

Comment: @MichaelE2 "Darn" too, because looking at the other question I suppose this one should be closed, and the Accepted answer there is essentially the same as my answer here, just a little less terse. :-/

Comment: This answer isn't very functional in its approach, is it?

Comment: @Jens What does that even mean?  I'm closing this question pending clarification.

Comment: @Jens Both our answers use an iterative function to generate an array.  If you are implying that yours is functional and mine isn't I'd love to hear your argument.

Comment: @Jens Then apparently I don't know what functional style is.  Why don't you extend the Question by clearly specifying your interpretation of functional programming?

Comment: @Jens I don't have a CS background and my opinion has no authority but quickly [refreshing my memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) I feel that my answer fits the definition of functional programming.  Would you at least explain to me why you believe it does not?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I updated the question with a clarification which I hope captures what the OP intended (judging simply from the fact that he accepted my answer).

Comment: @Jens I suppose it may be another case of my ignorance showing but I am thinking of `Array` as a declarative construct, not an imperative one.  My answer "feels" functional to me, but I may have a warped perspective.  If your argument is that this must be done through recursion shouldn't you give an explicit implementation rather than (only) using a high-level construct such as `CellularAutomaton`, whatever paradigm it belongs to?

Comment: @Jens You misunderstand me, and underestimate the respect that I have for you.  I learn a lot from your answers, at least those that I have the knowledge to understand, and I seek to learn from you again in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Pattern-based functional approach:

```
pat1 := n_Integer /; n > 1 :> Sequence[n, n - 1 /. pat1];
pat2 := v : List[__Integer] /; Max[v] > 1 :> Sequence[v, v - 1 /. pat2];

cb[n_] := MatrixPlot[
  {{n}} /. pat1 /. pat2,
  ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel@Mod[1 + #, 2] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotRangePadding -> None,
  FrameTicks -> {
    {#, #} &@ Table[{i, n - i + 1, 0}, {i, n}],
    {#, #} &@ Table[{i, FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode["a"] + i - 1], 0}, {i, n}]},
  FrameStyle -> Bold]

cb[8]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Expanding [eldos approach for even n](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58707/18476) to all integers > 0:

```
cb[n_?EvenQ] := 
 MatrixPlot[ArrayPad[DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}], n/2 - 1, "Reflected"], 
  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
cb[n_?OddQ] := 
 MatrixPlot[Most /@ Most @ ArrayPad[DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}], (n + 1)/2 - 1, "Reflected"], 
  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]

Manipulate[
 cb[n],
 {n, 1, 11, 1}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks @ Karsten - I was not able to find a solution for the odds.

Answer (score 3):

This is a functional version of `board`:

```
ones = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};
zeros = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
board[n_] := Partition[Riffle[ConstantArray[ones, (n)^2/2], {zeros}], n, n - 1] // ArrayFlatten // Image[#, ImageSize -> 400] &
board[8]
```

(Defining `ones` and `zeros` is optional, so this side effect can be avoided. You will notice also that it only works for even `n`.)

Comment: Executing your coding I get a long error message

Comment: @eldo I just restarted my kernel and tried it again, and it worked. Could you try restarting your kernel as well? (MMA10 btw, but shouldn't matter.)

Comment: Now it works (for even n). +1 for using `Image` :)

Answer (score 2):

Is what you mean by a functional solution a solution that uses functions?  Or do you mean in the style of functional programming?  If the former, then this works:

```
checked[n_] := Table[Mod[1 + (i + j), 2], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
numbers[n_] := Transpose[{Range[1, n], ToString /@ (Reverse@Range[1, n])}]
letters[n_] := Transpose[{Range[1, n], Characters@StringTake["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", n]}]
(* letters needs to know what to do past n = 26. *)

board[n_] := ArrayPlot[checked[n],
  FrameTicks -> {{False, numbers[n]}, {letters[n], False}}
  ]
```

Then, `board[8]` produces an image like the one you posted, while `board[11]` for example, gives an 11 x 11 board.  I have used the convention that a8 is always black, but the function `checked[n]` can be adjusted.

If you really need it in a functional programming style, you could do something like

```
squareColor = Function[{row, col}, Mod[row + col + 1, 2]]
checked = Function[n, Outer[squareColor, Range[1, n], Range[1, n]]]
board = Function[n, ArrayPlot[checked[n], 
   FrameTicks -> {{False, numbers@n}, {letters@n, False}}]
   ]
```

where I have left off the implementation of rank and file labeling for this style (but which can be easily redone in a functional style using the implementations above).